# The product of elements of the odd positions assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, multiplication

i have question , i hope you can help me to find the right solution

I wrote this code to calculate the addition of odd numbers in array using assembly x8086 .

I want now to calculate the multiplication of the elements of the odd POSITION

For example :
x DB 1,3,3,4,5,7
n DB 6 
The product is: 84 (produit de x [1], x [3], 
x [5])

Thank you

```
include 'emu8086.inc '   
org 100h  
LEA SI, array  
MOV AX,0  
MOV CX,0
MOV BX,1


for: 
CMP CX,n 
JGE endfor  
CMP CX,BX 
JNE else  

ADD AX,[SI]    
ADD CX,1
ADD BX,2
ADD SI,2


JMP endif 
else: 
ADD CX,1
ADD SI,2
endif:


JMP for
ENDFOR:



 call PRINT_NUM   
 ret 

  array dw 1,9,3,4,5,8,2
  n dw 7

  DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
  DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
  END
```

Comment: Your array in the code is words not bytes as in your text. For words, you need to add 4 to skip an element. Also I don't see any multiplication in your code.

Comment: My code is to make addition to the odd numbers ! now i want to make the multiplication of the odd position ! !

Comment: So use the `mul` instruction.  You're stuck on 8086, so you can't use the 2-operand `imul r16, r16`, and have to use the one-operand form [`imul r/m16`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html) with implicit ax and dx operands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change only 2 instructions in your program:

- Change `ADD AX,[SI]` into `mul word ptr [si]`. This leaves the product in DX:AX but since the numbers involved are so small the DX register will remain zero.
- Initialize the AX register with 1 instead of 0, else the product would always be zero! At the 4th line of this program change `MOV AX,0` into `mov ax,1`.

You could improve the program by moving the following lines below the "endif" label. They get executed in any case:

```
ADD CX,1
ADD SI,2
```